# How does google load the footer at the bottom of the page automatically?

Tags: php, css, footer

Google's footer on its homepage is always at the bottom of the browser when it is fully maximized despite the resolution.

How can I do a similar thing?

Comment: Search for "Sticky footer".

Answer (score 4):

Did you even tried to use your browser's inspect element tool?

The CSS:

```
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 10pt;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And this is the main div element for the footer (HTML):

```
<div class="ctr-p" data-jiis="bp" id="footer">
```

Short answer: the container's position is absolute set to the very bottom of its parent container, hence, bottom:0.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done using CSS with absolute positioning. Elements are positioned relative to their parents.

You can apply the following CSS to an element to have it anchored to the bottom of the page. CSS offers a `position` property that goes along with properties like `top` and `bottom`. Using `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` in this case will cause an element to be positioned such that it is 0px from the bottom of the parent element (if the parent is positioned relatively, otherwise I believe it is relative to the entire page).

You can learn more about absolute positioning with CSS at http://www.impressivewebs.com/absolute-position-css/